# Abstract factory pattern interface implementation or class extentsion

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, factory

Im currently implementing an abstract factory pattern for database connectivity, I need to separate business logic, and have code that does not need to be rewritten for each new database-type that needs to connect to my application, 
So at this point I have these classes

```
Interface Connection{}
MySql implements Connection{}
PostgreSql implements Connection{}
```

So the problem here is that each class that implements the interface Connection has to rewrite the methods in the interface, I would need a class where there are general methods like setStatement, executeQuery, etc, but then som methods would need to be overwritten like connect method which will differ depending on the databasetype,

My first thought is to have an extra class between the interface Connection and the subclasses,
where the methods are kept and used if not overridden, but this solution does not feel like the right way (correct me if im wrong)

```
Interface ConnectionInterface{}
class Connection{}
MySql extends Connection{}
PostgreSql extends Connection{}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd just use another name. Connection is already a JDBC entity.

Comment: name of my class is actually ConnectionBase but thx anyways

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with that. But I would do it like this:

```
interface Connection{}
abstract class AbstractConnection implements Connection {}
final class MySql extends AbstractConnection{}
final class PostgreSql extends AbstractConnection{}
```

With Java 8 you could also use default Methods in the interface and leave out the abstract class.

A completely alternative approach would be a class `DefaultConnectionOperations` that provides the methods. Then you could have an object of this class, which is injected into each Connection-Implementation. But it is arguable, if dependency injection is necessary in your case.

Comment: my problem is we are still using java 1.6.

Comment: What if I make the connection to an abstract class, and have the general methods and variables in that class, and have the subclasses to override some of the methods which will differ in their impl'? will that have an effect on the factory pattern?

Comment: @MRK187 You can do that, but the return type of the factory method should not be the abstract class, but an interface that abstract class implements. You should always use interfaces, because even an abstract class containing the default implementation may be exchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not consider the [State design pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1751/state-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) over inheritance. Here is an additional [very good post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225037/state-pattern-vs-inheritance) - why?

By doing so

> each new database-type

can alter an `Connection` behavior when its type changes. Also will appear already changed accordingly. The state pattern also allows you to keep attributes of a former state even when the state changes afterwards.

Pseudo code of the implementation:

```
class Connection{
private State _state;
}

abstract  class State{
protected Connection connection;
}

class MySqlState extends State{}
class PostgreSqlState extends State {}
```

Comment: allthough this feels like a awful lot of work, I could just have an abstract toplevel class and have other classes inherit, 
what is the difference? Seems like a hard way to achieve the same effect..

Comment: Better testability. Look at #5 advantage (unit testing) in this Database [post](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/04/30/the-state-pattern-an-underappreciated-pattern/) and how is related to “*favor composition over inheritance*” rule in OO design.

Comment: So in your pseudo are you refering to create an own class or import some existing class state?

Comment: If you can reuse some code it'll be better. But in the new State class you can  define logic for encapsulating the behavior associated with a particular state (MySql, PostgreSql, Oracle) of the Connection class.

Comment: I really dont understand the difference, except subclasses being able to change states, this will not be required in my implementation as the databases will come from different customers etc, 
So the easiest would be to have one class on top, and have other classes extend that class and override, why is this not to prefer?

Comment: It's up to you what will fit in your case best.  I don't know what is your implementation or design. I just tried to suggest you another approach since you can't use the @UniversE solution.

Comment: Ok, so I've restructured my hierarkie, i have an interface say connection, then I have the abstrakt class connection state, which implements the interface, any subclass will have to extend the ConnectionState class, ive set the methods that will need to be overriden, but Im not too sure how to handle the instance variables, is it ssmart to keep stuff like Connection in the state class, and have subclasses of the stateclass use them

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. Can you please try to fixed it. So correct me if I'm wrong but another thing that I see is that you didn't implement the State pattern correctly. Please see again the reference links. You *shouldn't* implement the Connection interface in the abstract class State. They have different roles.  The *Connection* should maintain an instance of a State() that defines the current state.

Comment: Ok well I'm refraining from the state pattern, and making my own solution based on the first answer thanks for ur help