# Abstract Factory pattern implementation

Tags: java, business-logic, abstract-factory

Hi Im following the abstract factorn pattern, and trying to figure out if this is the right way to go, for a database connection factory,

```
interface ConnectionInterface{//method declarations..}
abstract class ConnectionState implements interface{ //implementing all methods but one connect()}
final class SomedatabasSubclass extends ConnectionState{//only implied to override connect method}
//more subclasses extending the state
```

Ive posted this before but the discussion spiraled of to implementing other patternrs, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26256427/2323234 I need to seperate businesslogic from implementing classes, the pattern is secondary, and rewriting as little code as possible, this will be used in different products, so it will be used as an api so only some subclasses for that specific implementation will be required, as there will be databasestypes extending the api that is contained in a jar, 
In some product its oracle / mysql / etc, 
Other products will have different types of RDBMs as we talk to different customers dbs. So i need it to be on point basically to work in different enviornments, 
Also Im wondering about if the abstract ConnectionState class should keep all variables as Connections and results, statements etc
Thankful for your help,

Comment: Have you thought about using a persistence framework like hibernate?

Comment: Actually I have though about it, but I think this would add time and complexity, also we font want to have thirdparty dependencys in our systems,

Comment: Look at this post i e http://www.sickenger.com/2013/02/hibernate-just-stop-it/

Comment: Nice article. I tend to avoid Hibernate, too. Just wanted to know if it is an option for you. Have you considered using the sql2o-library mentioned there?